# How to import variables from typescript to sass? (Angular2 application)

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular2-components, css-variables

I am writing application (Angular2 framework).
And now I want to make different variables in sass files at development and production.

For example I want to use this solution:

```
@if $prod == true {
  $background-color: #fff;
} @else {
  $background-color: #333;
}
```

And i have $prod variable in my typescript file. But how i can pass it from typescript file to sass file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

1. Parse the scss file in the backend
2. Apply the style in javascript rather than the other way around